# QR Scanner react-native crash on second invocation

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, qr-code

Im using react-native-qrcode-scanner from https://github.com/moaazsidat/react-native-qrcode-scanner and I read perfectly the code but when I go back to qr-scanner again it crashes.
I think it is because the camera is still working on background, there is a way to close it when it ends?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are having the same issue as [this](https://github.com/moaazsidat/react-native-qrcode-scanner/issues/12) one on that github page.

And would recommend using that page to submit your problems regarding that software.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for navigation between Camera screen and others:

**In Constructor:**

```
this.state = {
  focusedScreen: true
};
```

**In render:**

```
  render() {

    const { focusedScreen } = this.state;

    if (!focusedScreen){
      return <View />;
    } else 
    {

      return (
          <QRCodeScanner ............
      )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <QRCodeScanner
    onRead={this.onSuccess.bind(this)}// change {this.onSuccess} to {this.onSuccess.bind(this)}
    topContent={
      <Text style={styles.centerText}>
        Go to <Text style={styles.textBold}>wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code</Text> on your computer and scan the QR code.
      </Text>
    }
    bottomContent={
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonTouchable}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>OK. Got it!</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    }
  />
```